# HTML page table pagination not showing the top of page

Tags: jquery

I have a working code from one page called:
oneSimpleTablePagination (see below) and need some help with it. If I go to page 2 or 3, 4, etc. it will always display new pages on the bottom part of the page. I need that every page (2, 3, 4....) will be displaying always top of the page. So if I click on next page I need to display this page from the top not from bottom part of it.

Any ideas how to modify this whole code to do it? Thanks

```
/**
 * OneSimpleTablePaging
 * - A small piece of JS code which does simple table pagination.
 *   It is based on Ryan Zielke's tablePagination 
 *   which is licensed under the MIT licenses
 *   Button designs are based on Google+ Buttons in CSS design from Pixify
 *   (http://pixify.com/blog/use-google-plus-to-improve-your-ui/).
 *
 * @author Chun Lin (GCL Project)
 *
 *
 * @name oneSimpleTablePagination
 * @type jQuery
 * @param Object userConfigurations:
 *      rowsPerPage - Number - used to determine the starting rows per page. Default: 10
 *      topNav - Boolean - This specifies the desire to have the navigation be a top nav bar
 *
 *
 * @requires jQuery v1.2.3 or above
 */
$("html").scrollTop(0);

$.prototype.extend(

                  {
        'oneSimpleTablePagination': function(userConfigurations) {
            var defaults = {
                rowsPerPage : 20,
                topNav : false
            };
            defaults = $.extend(defaults, userConfigurations);

            return this.each(function() {
                var table = $(this)[0];

                var currPageId = '#tablePagination_currPage';

                var tblLocation = (defaults.topNav) ? "prev" : "next";

                var tableRows = $.makeArray($('tbody tr', table));

                var totalPages = countNumberOfPages(tableRows.length);

                var currPageNumber = 1;       

                function hideOtherPages(pageNum) {
                    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
                    if (!intRegex.test(pageNum) || pageNum < 1 || pageNum > totalPages)
                        return;
                    var startIndex = (pageNum - 1) * defaults.rowsPerPage;
                    var endIndex = (startIndex + defaults.rowsPerPage - 1);
                    $(tableRows).show();
                    for (var i = 0; i < tableRows.length; i++) {
                        if (i < startIndex || i > endIndex) {
                            $(tableRows[i]).hide();
                        }
                    }
                }

                function countNumberOfPages(numRows) {
                    var preTotalPages = Math.round(numRows / defaults.rowsPerPage);
                    var totalPages = (preTotalPages * defaults.rowsPerPage < numRows) ? preTotalPages + 1 : preTotalPages;
                    return totalPages;
                }

                function resetCurrentPage(currPageNum) {
                    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
                    if (!intRegex.test(currPageNum) || currPageNum < 1 || currPageNum > totalPages)
                        return;
                    currPageNumber = currPageNum;
                    hideOtherPages(currPageNumber);
                    $(table)[tblLocation]().find(currPageId).val(currPageNumber);
                }

                function createPaginationElements() {
                    var paginationHTML = "";
                    paginationHTML += "<div id='tablePagination' style='text-align: center; border-top: solid 2px #0033CC; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;'>";
                    paginationHTML += "<a id='tablePagination_firstPage' href='javascript:;' class='button left'>prvá</a>";
                    paginationHTML += "<a id='tablePagination_prevPage' href='javascript:;' class='button right'>predošlá</a>";
                    paginationHTML += "Strana ";
                    paginationHTML += "<input id='tablePagination_currPage' type='input' value='" + currPageNumber + "' size='1'>";
                    paginationHTML += " z " + totalPages + "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";
                    paginationHTML += "<a id='tablePagination_nextPage' href='javascript:;' class='button left'>ďalšia</a>";
                    paginationHTML += "<a id='tablePagination_lastPage' href='javascript:;' class='button right'>posledná</a>";
                    paginationHTML += "</div>";
                    return paginationHTML;
                }

                $(this).before("<style type='text/css'>a.button {color: #023042;font: bold 12px Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;text-decoration: none;padding: 7px 12px;position: relative;display: inline-block;text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;-webkit-transition: border-color .218s;-moz-transition: border .218s;-o-transition: border-color .218s;transition: border-color .218s;background: #99CCFF;background: -webkit-gradient(linear,0% 40%,0% 70%,from(#38C1F9),to(#C6EDFD));background: -moz-linear-gradient(linear,0% 40%,0% 70%,from(#38C1F9),to(#C6EDFD));border: solid 1px #023042;border-radius: 2px;-webkit-border-radius: 2px;-moz-border-radius: 2px;margin-right: 10px;}a.button:hover {color: #247FCA;border-color: #247FCA;-moz-box-shadow: 0 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) -webkit-box-shadow:0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);box-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);}a.button:active {color: #000;border-color: #444;}a.left {-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 0;-moz-border-radius-topright: 0;border-top-right-radius: 0;-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 0;-moz-border-radius-bottomright: 0;border-bottom-right-radius: 0;margin: 0;}a.right:hover { border-left: solid 1px #999 }a.right {-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 0;-moz-border-radius-topleft: 0;border-top-left-radius: 0;-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 0;-moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 0;border-bottom-left-radius: 0;border-left: solid 1px #f3f3f3;border-left: solid 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);}</style>");

                if (defaults.topNav) {
                    $(this).before(createPaginationElements());
                } else {
                    $(this).after(createPaginationElements());
                }

                hideOtherPages(currPageNumber);

                $(table)[tblLocation]().find('#tablePagination_firstPage').click(function (e) {
                    resetCurrentPage(1);
                });

                $(table)[tblLocation]().find('#tablePagination_prevPage').click(function (e) {
                    resetCurrentPage(parseInt(currPageNumber) - 1);
                });

                $(table)[tblLocation]().find('#tablePagination_nextPage').click(function (e) {
                    resetCurrentPage(parseInt(currPageNumber) + 1);
                });

                $(table)[tblLocation]().find('#tablePagination_lastPage').click(function (e) {
                    resetCurrentPage(totalPages);
                });

                $(table)[tblLocation]().find(currPageId).on('change', function (e) {
                    resetCurrentPage(this.value);
                });

            })
        }
    })

$('#katalog').oneSimpleTablePagination({rowsPerPage: 20});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simple way to do it. You just need to change the following two lines.

```
topNav : false
```

Change to topNav : true.

```
paginationHTML += "<div id='tablePagination' style='text-align: center; border-top: solid 2px #0033CC; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px;'>";
```

Change the border-top to border-bottom.

Hope it helps!

Comment: thanks, severel days ago i have already soved it myself, but appreciate your help.